# How to install tkinter into pycharm community

Tags: tkinter

I am beginner of python , I am using pycharm community version to practice . And  now I want to make a program using GUI , for this I need tkinter module. There is not tkinter module installed in pycharm. How to install tkinter .I am using Ubuntu 16.04  lts.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking this in https://askubuntu.com or https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` or `sudo apt-get install python-tk` not work?

Comment: `PyCharm` is only IDE (editor with many features). `Python` and `tkinter` is not part of `IDE`. You can use `PyCharm` with different `Python` installed in system - it depends on your settings in PyCharm. Once I had PyCharm configured with `Python 2.7`, `Python 3`, `Anaconda Python` and `PyPy`. Mostly `Python` has `tkinter` preinstalled but once I saw Ubuntu without `tkinter` and I had to install it using apt-get as in @Nae comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of installing tkinter in pycharm itself, but I recommend using the command line way. To do it, open Pycharm and on them bottom, you should see a few tabs. Choose the “Terminal” option and then type:

```
pip3 install tkinter
```

Then you can open up your project and start by importing tkinter(assuming you know how to do it) and start writing you code.